# No ViewData localhost versus localhost in debug

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm stumped.  When I run my solution in debug mode, the entire website works.  It comes up with home page and everything. I can add, delete and update data to my database. The website was built with MVC, using SQLExpress (built in).

The issue is when I try to access the site either through localhost or from the outside world.  The site worked last year before I had to reinstall windows.  I upgraded from windows 7 to windows 8.1.

There's some kind of authentication that I'm missing.  Could someone point it out to me?

Permissions set
IIS_USRS, and IUSR have  modify, read & execute, list folder contents, read, and write

My physical path credentials is set to "Application User (pass-through authentication).

Application pool is using DefaultAppPool
.NET CLR Version v4.030319
Managed pipeline mode = Integrated

I had this issue before with windows 7, I thought I changed the DefaultAppPool process model identity to LocalService, or one of the other options.  None of them are working now.  Even tried to use a custom account.

Is there any more information I can provide?

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'YearID'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: There is no
>   ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key
>   'YearID'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 53:      Line 54:     Year: Line 55:     <%=
>   Html.DropDownList("YearID", ViewData["years"] as SelectList) %> Line
>   56:     
>  Line 57:     League:
>
> Source File:
>   e:\FantasyFootball\FantasyFootball\mvcFantasyFootball\FantasyFootball\Views\Home\Index.aspx

```
    FFBallEntities _db = new FFBallEntities();
    public ActionResult Navigation()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? leagueid, int? teamid)
    {
        try
        {
            bool ImMobile = DisplayModeProvider.MobileDisplayModeId.ToString() == "Mobile";

            if (!ImMobile)
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome To Fantasy Football Fantasy Edition!";
            }
            List<FanYear> years = _db.FanYearSet.OrderByDescending(m => m.FantasyYear).ToList();

            List<League> leagues = _db.LeagueSet.ToList();

            if (leagueid == null) leagueid = leagues[0].LeagueID;

            if (id == null)
            {
                id = _db.TeamSet.OrderByDescending(m => m.FanYear.YearID).Select(m => m.FanYear.YearID).First();
            }
            ViewData["years"] = new SelectList(years, "YearID", "FantasyYear", id);
            ViewData["leagues"] = new SelectList(leagues, "LeagueID", "League_Name", leagueid);
            ViewData["selectedyear"] = id.ToString();
            ViewData["selectedleague"] = leagueid.ToString();
            ViewData["selectedteam"] = "0";
            if (teamid != null)
                ViewData["selectedteam"] = teamid.ToString();


            int scoringid = _db.LeagueHistorySet.Include("FanYear").Include("Leagues").Include("Scoring").First(m => m.FanYear.YearID == id && m.Leagues.LeagueID == leagueid).Scoring.ScoringID;
            ViewData["selectedscore"] = scoringid.ToString();
            return View(_db.TeamScoreSet.Where(m => m.LeagueID == leagueid && m.YearID == id && (m.ScoringID == scoringid || m.ScoringID == 0)).OrderByDescending(m => m.PointsEarned).ToList());
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your error is occurring because the value of `ViewData["years"]` is `null` when you use the `DropDownList()` method. Probably because `ModelState` is invalid when you post your form and you have not reassign the `VIewData` property before you return the view. You need to show the relevant code from the controller methods associated with that view.

Comment: I can show you the code, the problem is that it's not with the code.  When I open the solution and bring up the website through the debugger, everything works.  Its when I try to access the site from my the outside world.  There's an authentication issue. I will update in a moment

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. It is because `ViewData["years"]` is `null`! The problem **is** with the code

Comment: Please explain to me why is works in debug mode?  If you can explain that, then I'm on board.

Comment: Show the GET and POST methods associated with the code.

Comment: @Michael No one can explain that to you without seeing the code. For all we know, you have a line saying `#if RELEASE throw new Exception(); #endif`

Comment: Added the code per request

Comment: `catch { return View(); }` looks very suspicious...

Comment: You code is throwing an exception which means in the `catch` block you return the view without setting the value of `ViewData["years"]`. Just add `ViewData["years"] = new SelectList(years, "YearID", "FantasyYear", id);` in the catch block before you return the view and that error will disappear.

Comment: Just adding that to the catch, didn't work because variable years wasn't provided. However, adding the code to get the data provided a different error.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

List<FanYear> years = _db.FanYearSet.OrderByDescending(m => m.FantasyYear).ToList();

Comment: @Michael, Now you know that you have an issue with connecting to the database. Perhaps an issue with the connection string, or with permissions. Suggest you google the error to find possible causes

Comment: I think it's because SQL server isn't installed.  I was thinking it was a part of the application.  DUH!!!   I'll get it installed.  Since web developer 2012 is no longer available for download, I forgot about needing SQL Server.  So I was running debug through my laptop, which has SQL Server installed.

Thank you.

Comment: I am wrong SQL server is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Me being an experienced web programmer, I should have known... (yet novice with .net and SQL server on windows platform).

The issue wasn't with the code, however, the code was preventing me from seeing the real error.  My try... catch threw out a message I wasn't expecting.

I was having difficulty getting passed the fact that the code worked when I run it on my laptop in debug mode.

The solution is stored and compiled on my server, however, I use the laptop to modify the code.

When I started it in debug, I figured it was still running off the server. But at last I was not.  I was using the SQL Express install on the laptop.

I have installed SQL Express 2012 on the server (which wasn't done when I reloaded the server), named the instance as I needed for the website.  The website is now communicating with the database.  I have other issues to resolve but I should be able to figure those out.  My javascript and css isn't getting pulled in. I'll post a new question if I have trouble getting it working.

Thank you for the help.